# Limiting unix time stamps in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm working on a blog in PHP/SQL etc and I have come across something I think is too advanced (obviously) for my SQL knowledge. I'm creating an archive section where, when posts are made, it stores the date/time of its post in UNIX timestamp format. However I want the archive to show like this:

```
Date     Year Post Count
-------- ---- ----------
November 2011 2
December 2011 1
```

I can easily get this:

```
Date     Year Post Count
-------- ---- ----------
November 2011 2
November 2011 2
December 2011 1
```

Hope you can see what I'm trying to achieve. My current SQL statement for this is:

```
SELECT `post_date` FROM `blog_posts` ORDER BY `post_date` DESC
```

PHP handles most of the sorting and there is a way I can achieve this in PHP but I'm sure there's an easier way in SQL.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Which database are you using? the syntax depends on the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [MySQL (5.5)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)  it would be close to following:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(post_date) AS month_col,
YEAR(post_date) AS year_col,
COUNT(*) AS num_posts
FROM blog_posts
GROUP BY YEAR(post_date), MONTH(post_date)
ORDER BY year_col, month_col DESC;
```

Would return:

```
December, 2011, 3
November, 2011, 2
December, 2010, 1
```

Comment: thanks for your example managed to sort it 

`SELECT MONTHNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(`post_date`)) AS archiveMonth, YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(`post_date`)) as `archiveYear`, COUNT(*) as `num_posts` FROM `blog_posts` GROUP BY `archiveMonth` ORDER BY `archiveMonth` DESC`

And thanks for everyone else who helped!

Comment: Please accept the answer if you feel it was correct or near enough.
Also, note that the example query you posted above will group Dec2011 and Dec2012 to same Dec group and the COUNT will be wrong. You will have to add the year as grouping criteria as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which SQL you are using but if it is MySQL, something like below should work.

```
SELECT post_date, COUNT(*) 
FROM blog_posts 
GROUP BY post_date / 86400
ORDER BY post_date DESC
```

86400 comes from 24 * 60 * 60, number of seconds in a day.

Comment: Thanks page will try this and yeah MySql